# How can i receive input of voice by microphone - python

Tags: python

I want to receive input of voice from the user and save the voice to mp3 file or somthing.
How can i do it with python?
Is there any library or somthing that i can use in python to do this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

PyAudio can get the job done.